# How do I take data from a datatable and create Dynamic panels in C#?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable in a database that has IP camera information in it (IP address, username, password, etc.) and I have a winform that displays the IP camera feed.  Right now, if I want to add a new camera I would have to hard code everything, but I was wondering if I could make it so that when a new camera is added to the datatable a new panel with the picturebox and everything on it would be created programmatically.

I have been reading about Dynamic panels, but I haven't found anything that I can use.  I don't even know where to start with this, otherwise I would put code that I have.  Does anyone have an idea or a link to look at?

if that is too much, then to get me started, how could I programmatically create how ever many rows my datatable has of panels?  So if my datatable has 3 rows, then on the app start 3 panels will be created.  If I change the number of rows to 6, then on the next start up 6 panels will be created.  Also, if I take away a panel and it now has 2 rows, then the next time I start the app 2 panels will be created.

I hope it is clear what I am asking and if not please ask and I will try to explain better.

Comment: Yes, I currently have a winform as I stated, and I want to do it in a winform still.

Comment: You can instantiate a new panel based on your data, then add it as a child to your form.  When you read about "dynamic panels" is that a specific type of panel?

Comment: How would I instantiate a new panel based on my data?  what I mean by "dynamic panels" is panels that are created on the start of the app.  Because the number of panels may be different based on how many cameras are in the datatable.

Comment: Loop through the rows, and for every row, create a new panel and add it to the parent's control collection.  Look inside your designer file to see how the designer is doing it for you to get the gist of it.  The parent control should probably be a FlowLayoutPanel.  If you want other controls inside each panel, then you really should create a UserControl instead, and add that instead of a panel.

Comment: Do you know if AForge.net can be used with UserControls?  I've been practicing with UserControls and get an error when I have an AForge library.